# VS2017 Misleading Error Line Identification

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

In VS 2017 VB.Net the debugger is stopping at the wrong line when it finds an error. But not consistently and not related to end of line inconsistency. The behaviour is very odd because so far I have found that it only seems to affect Object and String arrays, other arrays that cause an error get identified correctly. Create a form with some buttons, I have used 4 for this example. Enter the following code as the button handlers. Note that the code in each handler is identical apart from the array type. The debugger will stop at the wrong line, but only in the handlers that have object and string arrays. It stops at the line after the one that has the error. I have looked around and seen the solutions for inconsistent line endings but VS is not complaining of this, it's a brand new project with no code other than what you see below and even if it was inconsistent line endings why should the debugger mislead me only for certain types? I spent hours this morning chasing a non-existent bug in the wrong array. Cheers.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myArray(1) As Integer 'Note: INTEGER ok
        myArray(1) = 0 'This line is valid and executes ok
        myArray(2) = 0 'This line is correctly identified as an out of bounds error
        myArray(1) = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim myArray(1) As Object ' Note: OBJECT not ok
        myArray(1) = 0 'This line is valid and executes ok
        myArray(2) = 0 'This Line should show as an out of bounds error but it doesn't
        myArray(1) = 0 'This line is still valid but is now incorrectly identified as the error line
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim myArray(1) As Double 'Note: DOUBLE ok
        myArray(1) = 0 'This line is valid and executes ok
        myArray(2) = 0 'This line is correctly identified as an out of bounds error
        myArray(1) = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        Dim myArray(1) As String ' Note: STRING not ok
        myArray(1) = 0 'This line is valid and executes ok
        myArray(2) = 0 'This Line should show as an out of bounds error but it doesn't
        myArray(1) = 0 'This line is still valid but is now incorrectly identified as the error line
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I can definitely reproduce and it's pretty weird. Note that the actual exception shows the correct line (if you look at the stacktrace), it's the IDE that marks the wrong line. Pretty weird

Comment: Btw, I initially thought it would be something like "reference types" vs "value types", but it isn't... I created a class and used it for the array type and then the IDE shows the correct line throwing

Comment: Hmya, you are paying the price for programming with Option Strict Off in effect.  The actual exception happens in a helper function that they can't show you.  It does the "right thing" and raises the exception in your own code.  The only address they have of that code is the return address on the stack.  Unfortunately that address points at the statement *after* the call to the helper function.  Which happens to be the next statement in your vb.net code.  You can file the bug with Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem, but I don't think there is much use to it, very hard to fix.

Comment: Jcl: Thanks for the confirmation and extra investigation, I also tried Lists to see if lists of objects vs. lists of integers behaved the same but they seem to work fine.
Hans: Thanks for the very clear, concise but in depth explanation and confirmation that it is a bug. BTW I always program with Option Strict On. If it had been around years ago when I started programming it would save me hours of degbugging. In the example I gave Option Strict was off by default and I left the numeric to String conversion to the compiler just so that I could keep all four button handlers the same.